# Sass division not working

Tags: css, sass, calc

For some reason, Sass's division is not working.

```
@mixin tabs($num-of-tabs) {
  .slide {
    width:(100% / #{$num-of-tabs});
    width: calc(100% / #{$num-of-tabs});
  }
}
```

I want to set the width without using calc and then with it. This is for an IE10 fallback.

But it doesn't compile the way I'd expect.

The CSS it outputs is

```
.slide-demo {
  width: 100%/3;
  width: calc(100% / 3); 
}
```

I need it to output 33.33% for the width, not 100%/3, which CSS cannot understand.

Comment: From memory SASS division works on integers and doubles. Have you tried `(100 / 3) + '%';`?

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks for the response, but unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot (sorry long time since I was using SASS) try this: `width: unquote((100 / 3) + "%");`